# JSONObject in org.json lib: utf-8 encoding issue

Tags: json, encoding, utf-8, org.json

I'm following the [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.it/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) post.

The only issue I have is with JSONObject encoding (I'm using `org.json` lib).

The issue arises when I put a string like `àòùèì€€`, for example, in a JSONObject.

```
System.out.println(entry.getValue());
JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();
temp.put("values", entry.getValue();
System.out.println(temp.toString());
```

I obtain `àòùèì€€` and `{"values":"àòùèì\u20ac\u20ac"}` instead of `{"values":"àòùèì€€"}`.

**EDIT**

By passing from an hashtable to a jsonObject, the extended utf-8 encoding is used. For example, the hashtable

```
 {€èòàùì€ù=èòàù€ì, €òàèùì€=èòàù€ìç§$}
```

becomes the JSONObject

```
 {"\u20acòàèùì\u20ac":"èòàù\u20acìç§$","\u20acèòàùì\u20acù":"èòàù\u20acì"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are exactly equal, with the Unicode escaping taking a bit more space. Like writing `\u004a` in Java is exactly the same as writing `a`. If correctness is your concern, it doesn't matter.

And it won't take considerable amount of extra space either unless most of your text is between 0x2000 - 0x20FF:

[The following code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java#L1250) escapes C0 and C1 control characters, but it also escapes 0x2000 - 0x20FF:

```
     if (c < ' ' || (c >= '\u0080' && c < '\u00a0')
                    || (c >= '\u2000' && c < '\u2100')) {
```

So any character between 0x2000 - 0x20FF and control characters are represented as unicode escapes. This makes sense for control characters because those are not allowed in JSON in their unescaped form.

As for 0x2000 - 0x20FF, I have no idea because the code is not commented. Every character unescaped in that range is valid JSON. [Of course, `0x2028` and `0x2029` are not valid in Javascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.3) (so this small detail makes JSON syntax not a subset of Javascript syntax), so it's good idea to escape those in JSON in case it is being used as JSONP which is Javascript really. But it is not apparent to me why the code escapes a whole range because just 2 characters in the range are illegal.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that in a jsp page with pageencoding utf-8 and content-type utf-8, if I print the `àòùèì\u20ac\u20ac` I see `àòùèì\u20ac\u20ac` and not `àòùèì€€`.

Comment: @Cricket yes, but when you decode the JSON, you will get `€€` in the decoded objects. The encoded JSON is never used for other than data transfer/storage, you will always decode it before using because it makes no sense to operate on the JSON as a string.

Comment: What do you mean with decode? I get the string from db with `rs.getString("json")` and I parse it by using Java String. What should I do?

Comment: @Cricket by decode I mean like using `JSON.parse` in Javascript to turn the JSON string returned from server into something useable by Javascript. How are you using the JSON on your page?

Comment: In a servlet I retrieve the json string from a mysql db (that use utf-8 for character set and collations). This string is passed to an utility method of mine. This method parses the string and creates another string with html tag. This last string is put in the request, so the receiving jsp can display it.

Comment: @Cricket what is the purpose of displaying JSON? Are you making some kind of JSON tutorial or a site for programmers? I would expect to see `<div>àòùèì€€</div>` instead of `<div>{"values":"àòùèì€€"}</div>` in any other case.

Comment: the json string represents field form name-value (the forms are created by using a jquery lib and they are saved like jason strings. The same as concerns the user input).

Comment: @Cricket but that doesn't answer my question at all, what are you trying to do? It makes no sense to display the JSON directly on the page.

Comment: I'll try to explain. The form user input is saved as a json string like `{"fieldname":"value", "fieldname2":"value2"}`. I have to display these infos (I could have more fields with the same name). The parsing is quite easy, but the unicode escaping isn't translated.

Comment: @Cricket I am not talking about parsing on server side but on client side. For example, if you use it like this on client-side: http://jsfiddle.net/Ru2BY/1/.

Comment: I would to find a server side solution, nevertheless thank you for the example.

Comment: @Cricket What would the server side solution do? You still need to parse the JSON on client side, the server cannot do anything about that.

Comment: I've resolved by creating (in the server-side parsing) a JSONObject from the string retrieved from the db.