# why does org.json.JSONArray constructor converts some utf-8 characters to unicode?

Tags: java, json, unicode, utf-8, org.json

For the code `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resourceJSONStr);` if `resourceJSONStr`  has `"name":"US_NE€あé¥₭"`, in resultant `jsonArray` its `"name":"US_NE\u20acあé¥\u20ad"`
why does org.json.JSONArray constructor converts some utf-8 characters to unicode?

Comment: See [JSONObject in org.json lib: utf-8 encoding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895709/jsonobject-in-org-json-lib-utf-8-encoding-issue)

Comment: ok. I need to write the resultant jsonArray to a file and I dont want unicodes there, I want the actual utf-8 character. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you get data from Rest API by the using Rest-Template. So you use that

`RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.
            getMessageConverters()
            .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));`